# 'qrsh' fails with error message: "error: getcwd() failed"

Tags: directory, qsub, sungridengine

I am using [SGE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Grid_Engine) under Linux and cannot run [`qrsh`](http://manpages.org/qrsh). It fails with the error message below:

```
$ qrsh -now no -pe smp 1
error: getcwd() failed
```

Comment: I just self-closed this Q as a dupe. Is this OK? I wanted the next person who steps on this rake to be able to quickly find the answer. But without duplicating this solution, it's been duplicated **enough**.

Comment: This post is being discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374908).